# Как создать условие, которое проверяет переменная ссылочного типа или нет в Java?

Tags: java, типы

Как в java  создать простой метод, который принимает атрибут и если этот атрибут ссылочного типа, то писать  в консоль "correct type" , а если атрибут не ссылочного типа, то выдавать "incorrect type"?

Comment: А как вы передадите в метод аргумент, который можеть быть ссылкой или примитивным типом?

Comment: да, видимо это невозможно проверить

Comment: Метод может принимать ссылочный тип, либо конкретный примитивный тип (int,long ...) . В таком случае проверять нечего.

Comment: Смысл в том, что есть есть некая переменная которую я должен проверить  сходится ли тип этой переменной с типом итератора в случае если тип перменной имеет ссылочный тип. И вот я хочу понять сначала тип перменной имеет ссылочный тип или нет прежде чем сравнивать его с типом итератора.

Comment: Если вы про java.util.Iterator, то он, как и все женерики, работает только с ссылочным типом.

Comment: Да, про него. Т.е. смысл проверять тип переменной имеет ссылочный или примитивный тип не имеет, а можно сразу сверять тип  итератора и тип переменной?

Comment: а для это вообще нужно, какова в целом задача ?